# How to use two mail servers in parallel, if possible?

Tags: email, email-server, gmail

I basically want to have two separate email servers. The first one is the GoogleApps GMail service, which is for humans to use. The second server would be for sending messages from my application (so, send them programatically).

Do I even need to reference second mail server (on the same IP as my application) in MX-records (or wherever this would have to be referenced)? I wouldn't like the emails to get flagged spam or as "suspicious."

On a side note, I might use this mail server to process some "special" types of messages (like all messages sent to support@example.com). [I found a related question for this](https://serverfault.com/questions/222875/can-i-use-multiple-email-servers-at-once), but I am not sure it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your application can send mail directly from its application server, provided you take some steps to ensure that your outbound mail doesn't get flagged as spam. This includes setting [reverse PTR (DNS) records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) for the sending server's IP address. Possibly some manipulation of headers and maybe an SPF record...

Another option is to relay your application's mail through Gmail (not worth it) or through another trusted [Smart Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host).

Also take a look at: [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

Answer (score 3):

If the second server is only *outbound* for applications, and Google Mail is for inbound and outbound (i.e. normal usage by users), then there is no need to touch the MX record.

Just add the IP of the *second* server to a SPF Record, which requires access at the DNS level of your domain.

There are several wizards online to assist you in the syntax.

http://www.spfwizard.net/